# How to select every 4th row in a pandas dataframe and calculate the rolling average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that you can see in the screenshot. The dataframe has a time resolution of 15 minutes (it is generation data). I would like to reduce this time resolution to 1 hour meaning that I should take every 4th row and the value in every 4th row should be the anverage values of the last 4 rows (including this one). So it should be a rolling average with non-overlapping horizons.

I tried the following for one column (wind offshore):

```
df_generation = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Data/generation_data.csv", sep =",")
df_generation_2 = df_generation
df_generation_2['Wind Offshore Average'] = df_generation_2['Wind Offshore'].rolling(4).mean()
```

But this is not what I really want. As you can see in the screenshot, my code just created a further column with the average of the last 4th entries for every timeslot. Here the rolling average has overlapping horizons. What I want is to have a new dataframe that only has an entry after every hour (after 4 timslots of the original array). Do you have an idea how I can do that? I'd appreciate every comment.

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your Index it looks like the .resample method is what you are looking for (with many examples for specific uses): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

as in

```
new = df_generation['Wind Offshore'].resample('1H').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks Cider for the anwer but this is not the output I want to get. With your suggested approach the number of rows is increased by 4 (with 3 out of 4 values having nan entries)

Comment: Might i suggest changing `'4T` to `'1H'`? 'T' stands for minuTes, so this would resample every 4 minutes, rather than every hour.

Comment: My bad... try, df_generation['Wind Offshore'].resample('1H').mean() instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cider and David. Basically now it looks good. I have 2 follow up questions to this: 1) With the suggested code I just did it for "wind offshore". How can this be automatically done for every column of the original dataframe? 2) With the suggested code the label of the column is just "Actual aggregated". How can this be automatically changed to "wind offshore" and the other corresponding column names when considering multipel columns?

Comment: And another follow up question 3) In order to use this approach with the string arguments e.g. '1H' or '1T', the date values have to have a special format right? How does this format has to look like? In my case the format is  "2021-04-20 00:00:00+02:00". Are other formats also possible? I'd appreciate every further comments

Comment: Hi Cider, thanks a lot for your answer and effort. Any comments on my last 2 comments containing 3 follow-up questions? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Any comments on my last comments?

Comment: Peter... As I mentioned. you have a link, with a lot of examples of how to handle resample. Read through it (hint: keyword - on)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cider. I will have a look at the link later. I accepted and upvoted your answer.