# TypeError when resampling a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to resample every 4th row in a Pandas dataframe. As suggested [How to select every 4th row in a pandas dataframe and calculate the rolling average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215322/how-to-select-every-4th-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-the-rolling-aver) here I use the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



#Read the input data
df_generation = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Data/Electricity Price Forecasting/Generation.csv", sep =";")
print(df_generation.dtypes)
df_generation_short = df_generation[0:2000]
df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])

new = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()
```

I convert the column time in the original dataframe into a datetime because otherwise pandas sees it as an object type (as recommended here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703538/typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex-but-got)
However, I still get the error message

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I also get a warning before the error telling me:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Here you can see a screenshot of the dataframe[image: Screenshot]

Do you know why I get this error and how I can solve the problem? I'd appreciate every comment.

Update: I tried it with the suggestion from one comment and used the apply function:
`df_generation_short.apply(pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time']))` but I get the error message "ValueError: no results". Does anyone have another idea how to solve the problem? Somehow pandas does not accept the column "Time" as a date object with an index altough I convert it by using `df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])`.

Comment: you should use function `apply` to your object `df_generation_short`

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your comment. Where and how should I use apply?

Comment: @dallonsi: I tried `df_generation_short.apply(pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time']))` and I get the error message "ValueError: no results"

Comment: about your `SettingWithCopyWarning`: I suggest you read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087

Comment: which line raises your `TypeError`? `df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])` or `new = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()` ?

Comment: can you print `df_generation_short['Time']` please ?

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your comments. The type error is caused by the line `new = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()` and the value error is caused by the line `df_generation_short.apply(pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time']))`

Comment: Here is the output of `print(df_generation_short["Time"])` when using it before the statement `df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])` or (`df_generation_short.apply(pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time']))`):

Comment: `0       2018-04-21 00:00:00+02:00
1       2018-04-21 00:15:00+02:00
2       2018-04-21 00:30:00+02:00
3       2018-04-21 00:45:00+02:00
4       2018-04-21 01:00:00+02:00
           
1995    2018-05-11 18:45:00+02:00
1996    2018-05-11 19:00:00+02:00
1997    2018-05-11 19:15:00+02:00
1998    2018-05-11 19:30:00+02:00
1999    2018-05-11 19:45:00+02:00
Name: Time, Length: 2000, dtype: object`

Comment: according to the doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html you're not using the resample method `resample('1H')` on a Time-like index. Indeed, you're using it on column `Biomass` instead of (maybe) column `Time`

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your answer. Basically I do it exactly as it is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215322/how-to-select-every-4th-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-the-rolling-aver. There this approach worked. Unfortunately now it does not work on the my current dataframe posted above and I still do not know why

Comment: Basically pandas does not accept the column "time" as a time or date object but just as a conventional object. This is why it can't do the resampling. As a consequence of this I try to tell pandas that this is a "date" object by using the line `df_generation_short['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])`  (as remommended here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703538/typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex-but-got) and it accepts this. However, I still get the type error when trying to resample.

Comment: ok. But the problem is that you can only resample with `resample('1H')` on a column containing dates  ! (`Biomass` does not contain dates)

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your comment. Have a look at this question (that I also asked): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215322/how-to-select-every-4th-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-the-rolling-aver. Here it is exactly the same and I use the code `new = df_generation['Wind Offshore'].resample('1H').mean()` to resaample the column "Wind Offshore" which is also - like Biomass - not a date. And it worked perfectly (and it is also the suggested code by 2 persons). However, I am quite confused because with this dataframe it does not work now. So I think there is an issue with the "Time"

Comment: Ok ! I guess I have an idea. In your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215322/how-to-select-every-4th-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-the-rolling-aver your index column is a date. However, it's not the case for your dataFrame `df_generation_short`. Try this before resampling: `df_generation_short = df_generation_short.set_index('Time')`

Comment: Thanks a lot dallonsi for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Yes, this in fact solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your tremendous help (if you write this in an answer, I would upvote and accept it such that you get the points).

Comment: Maybe one follow up question: How can I resample all columns and create a new dataframe with all columns resampled? With my approach I have to do it for every column individually. Is there a way how this can be done automatically (maybe with a for loop)?

Comment: yes, I'll make an answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up our conversation:

- This line `new = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()` throws the TypeError:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

- This is because the column `Biomass` does not contain dates inputs. Thus, in order to solve this problem, set your DataFrame index to column `Time`:

```py
df_generation_short = df_generation_short.set_index('Time')
```

- Now, if you want to get the mean values of `Biomass` in a window of 1 hour,

```py
new = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()
```

- Moreover, if you want to compute this mean over all columns, just omit to specify the column

```py
new = df_generation_short.resample('1H').mean()
```

Or if you want it for two specific columns: "Biomass" and "Fossil Oil" for instance:

```py
new = df_generation_short[["Biomass", "Fossil Oil"]].resample('1H').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dallonsi. Basically I have experienced a problem. When applying your suggested code on a shortenend dataframe created by using `df_generation_short = df_generation[0:2000]` it works perfectly. But when using it on the whole dataframe I get the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This code works using the short Dataframe: `df_generation = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Data/Electricity Price Forecasting/Generation.csv", sep =";")
df_generation['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation['Time'])
df_generation = df_generation.set_index('Time')
df_generation_short = df_generation[0:2000]
new_shortDataframe = df_generation_short['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()`

Comment: While this code using the whole dataframe leads to the above mentioned TyperError: `df_generation = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Data/Electricity Price Forecasting/Generation.csv", sep =";")
df_generation['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation['Time'])
df_generation = df_generation.set_index('Time')

new_wholeDataframe = df_generation['Biomass'].resample('1H').mean()`

Comment: ok, on the entire DataFrame (i.e. do not use: `df_generation_short = df_generation[0:2000]`) , does the line `pd.to_datetime(df_generation_short['Time'])` throw an error ? It could happen because your DataFrame contains "bad" entries

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your answer. The line `df_generation['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_generation['Time'])` does not throw any error or warning

Comment: I am out of ideas. Maybe, run a loop : `for k in range(2000, 10000)` and replace `df_generation[0:2000]` by  `df_generation[:k]`, print `k` in your loop, see for which `k` in fails, look back in your dataframe at line `k` to see if this line has a strange entry

Comment: Thanks dallonsi for your answer and suggestion. Basically I figured out what the problem is but I still have to think about how to solve it. The problem is the change from summer/winter time. Because of this the time values of specific hours exists two times while for other  hours no values exist. But this might be another question. I would like to thank you for your tremendous help and effort. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.